# sorting by class color in angular2

Tags: angular

I'm tryin to sort a table depending on the color of a radio button (element.IsOnline). I'm tryin to sort by date last seen but, even though the format seems to be ok, doesn't sort. That's why I'm trying to do it bu green or red, but no idea how can i do it.

How can I do it?

my .html

```
 <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class=" mat-elevation-z8">


              <ng-container matColumnDef="online">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header></th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                  <i *ngIf="element.isOnline" class="material-icons"
                    style="color: rgba(0, 100, 0, 0.80)">radio_button_checked</i>
                  <i *ngIf="!element.isOnline" class="material-icons"
                    style="color: rgba(190, 0, 0, 0.80)">radio_button_checked</i>
                </td>
              </ng-container>

 <ng-container matColumnDef="deviceName">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Device Id </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.deviceName}} </td>
              </ng-container>

            <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
              <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: displayedColumns;" (click)="goToDeviceDetails(element)">
              </tr>

 <ng-container matColumnDef="lastSeen">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Last seen </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.telemetryUtc | date: 'medium'}} </td>
              </ng-container>
            </table>
```

my .ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, ViewEncapsulation, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";

import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';

@Component({
  selector: "app-provisioned-list",
  templateUrl: "./provisioned-list.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./provisioned-list.component.scss"],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  animations: fuseAnimations
})
export class ProvisionedListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  deviceList: DeviceModel[];
  displayedColumns: string[] = ["checkbox", "online", "deviceName", "tags", "actualVersion", "status", "runningApps", "appVersion", "lastSeen"];

 @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
 devices: any;

private getDeviceList() {
    this.provisionedService.getProvisionedDevicesList().then(response => {
      this.deviceErrorMessage = null;
      this.dataSource.data = response;

this.dataSource.data.map(device => {
        this.provisionedService.getIsDeviceAlive(device._id).then(response => device.isOnline = response);

  }
```

Comment: Is the underlying type of the lastSeen Date or string?

Comment: telemetryUtc: "2020-04-23T16:40:30.000Z" It's a date

Comment: created has the same format and it sorts it just fine. Just edited the question to show last seen